# If $f(z)$ is real periodic and $g(z)$ is complex periodic , Can $g(z+f(z))$ be periodic?

Tags: complex-numbers, periodic-functions

Let $A$ be a nonzero real number and let $B$ be a nonreal complex number.
Let $z$ be a complex number.
Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be non-constant functions defined for all complex numbers $z$ and satisfy

$f(z+A)=f(z),$
$g(z+B)=g(z)$

and $B$ is not a period of $f$ and $A$ is not a period of $g$.

Is it possible that $g(z+f(z))$ is periodic ?

Comment: Do you mean $g(z+B) = g(z)$ instead of $g(z+B)=z$ ? If so then if $A=B$ we find that $h(z) = g(z+f(z))$ satisfy $h(z+A) = h(z)$.

Comment: Ahhh the $A=B$ condition conflicts with $B$ nonreal complex...so the above example does not work.

Comment: So far you haven't ruled out $f$ being the constant function $B$, which trivially makes $g(z+f(z))$ periodic.

Comment: @GregMartin $f$ is real, $B$ is not so this does not work.

Comment: No @Winther, I think Greg is correct , a constant is double period afterall.
Thanks for you helpfull comments though.
Also thank you  at GregMartin

Comment: I see where you say $A$ is real, but nowhere that $f$ must be real-valued.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I read real periodic as meaning real. Though the problem gets much more interesting if this was the case.

Comment: Sure, for example if $B$ is *also* a period of $f$ or $A$ is also a period of $g$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks. I realized that , but I had to put it in the OP which I did in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are functions $\theta(z)$, with a 1-cyclic real period, and $g(z), \;h(z)$, are complex periodic functions where $h(z)=g(z+\theta(z))$ and $g(z)$ has a different complex period than $h(z)$.

I generate an example solution below, using complex dynamics.  Consider iterating the function $f(z)=z^2+z-0.01$  Also, we could use other small negative values other than -0.01, to generate two fixed points.

$f(z)$ has two fixed points, -0.1 and 0.1, where $f(-0.1)=-0.1\;\;\;\;f(0.1)=0.1\;\;\;\;$  You can develop the Schroeder function at either fixed point.  0.1 is a repelling fixed point, -0.1 is an attracting fixed point.

Now consider the first half of the solution to the Op's function as $g(z)=f^{o z}(0)\;\;\;\;g(z+1)=f(g(z))$, where $f^{o z}(0)$ is generated from the +0.1 fixed point using the inverse Abel function $\alpha^{-1}(z)$, and the Abel function is generated from standard Schroeder function solution around the +0.1 fixed point.  $g(z)$ is a complex periodic function with a period of $\frac{2\pi i}{\ln(\lambda)}$ where $\lambda$ is the multiplier at the fixed point.  For the fixed point of 0.1, $\lambda=\frac{6}{5}$ since $f(0.1+x)=0.1+\frac{6x}{5}+x^2$, and the period is $\approx 34.462i$, so the $g(z)$ function is imaginary periodic, and is generated from the Schroeder equation for $y \mapsto \frac{6}{5}y+y^2;\;\; y=z-0.1\;\;\;\;$  Also, $g(z)$ turns out to be entire.  Here is the periodic Fourier series form for $g(z)$.

$$g(z) = 0.1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left( \frac{6}{5} \right) ^ {nz} $$

Now, consider another function $h(z)$, which is generated from the other -0.1 fixed point in much the same way.  It turns out that $h(z)=g(z+\theta(z))$, where $\theta(z)$ is a 1-cyclic periodic function, $\theta(z+1)=\theta(z)$.  But first, back to $h(z)$.

$h(z)=f^{o z}(0)\;\;\;\;h(z+1)=f(h(z))$, but this time we are using the other fixed point of -0.1, which is an attracting fixed point.  $h(z)$ is generated from the -0.1 fixed point using the inverse Abel function $\alpha^{-1}(z)$, and the Abel function is generated from standard Schroeder function solution around the -0.1 fixed point.  $h(z)$ is a complex periodic function with a period of $\frac{2\pi i}{\ln(\lambda)}$ where $\lambda$ is the multiplier at the fixed point.  For the fixed point of -0.1, $\lambda=\frac{4}{5}$ since $f(-0.1+x)=-0.1+\frac{4x}{5}+x^2$, and the period is $\approx 28.157i$  The $h(z)$ function is imaginary periodic, and is generated from the Schroeder equation for $y\mapsto \frac{4}{5}y+y^2;\;\; y=z+0.1\;\;\;\;$ $h(z)$ has square root branches where $h(z)=-0.5$.  These singularities occur at half the imaginary period of $h(z)$, plus any multiple of the period; one of them is near $z\approx 4.0831 \pm 14.0788i$.  $h(z)$ is analytic to the right of this singularity, and where also where $|\Im(z)|<\approx 14.0788i$

$$h(z) = -0.1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^ {nz} $$

Both $h(z)$ and $g(z)$ are real valued at the real axis; both have the same defining iteration equations, and for integer values of z, $h(z)=g(z)$.  They disagree very slightly on fractional iterations, which is what leads to $\theta(z)$.  Both h(z) and g(z) have a limiting value of -0.1 as real z gets arbitrarily large positive, and a limiting value of 0.1 as z real z gets arbitrarily large negative. g(z) is well defined for complex values of z if $\Re(z)$ is a large negative number, where $g(z)\approx 0.1+1.2^{z+k}$, and is imaginary periodic, with values cycling around 0.1 with an imaginary period of $\approx 34.462i$.  At half the imaginary period, $g(z)$ grows from the 0.1 repelling fixed point and gets arbitrarily large.  $h(z)$ is well defined in the complex plane if $\Re(z)$ is a large positive number, where $h(z)\approx -0.1$, and $h(z)$ is also imaginary periodic, and $h(z) \approx -0.1 + 0.8^{z+k}$ is cycling around -0.1 with a different imaginary period of $\approx 28.157i$

So, it turns out that there is a small one cyclic periodic function, $f(z)=\theta(z)$.  $\theta(z)$ is analytic at the real axis, and has a 1-cyclic singularity at $z \approx n + 0.0831 \pm 14.0788i$, where the singularities of $h(z)$ are.  And, an example solution to the Op's question becomes:

$$h(z)= g(z+\theta(z))$$

Here is a picture of the iterated function $f^{o z}(0)$ at the real axis, from -25 to +25, where it gradually goes from +0.1 to -0.1, where $f(z)=z^2+z-0.01$  Integer values of $f^{o z}$ can be trivially generated by iterating $z \mapsto z^2+z-0.01$ or iterating the inverse function, $f^{-1}(z)$ which is $z \mapsto \sqrt{z+0.26}-0.5$.  For fractional iterations of $f^{o z}$, there are two very slightly different solutions, depending on whether we develop the iterated function from the attracting fixed point of -0.1 at $+\infty$ or the repelling fixed point of +0.1 at $-\infty$.  These two solutions for $f^{o z}(0)$ can be generated from the two formal Schroeder equations for the two fixed points, although the formal solution needs to be scaled so that g(0)=0 and h(0)=0.  I can add later.

[image: ghfunc picture]

Here is a graph of the tiny real valued 1-cyclic $\theta(z)$ function at the real axis, from -1 to +1.  As you can see, its magnitude is $|\theta(z)| \lt 8 \cdot 10^{-40}$
[image: theta]

Here is a graph of $\left(g(z)-0.1\right)$ at $\;\;\Re(z)=-25$.  I used the iteration function $y \mapsto \frac{6y}{5}+y^2$ where $z=y+0.1$ and $z \mapsto z+z^2-0.01$. Here, $g(z)$ has an imaginary period of $\frac{2\pi i}{\ln(1.2)}\approx 34.462i$.  The graph goes from $z=-25-18i$ to $z=-25+18i\;\;$  Red is imaginary and magenta is real.  A similar graph could be generated for $h(z)+0.1$ at $\Re(z)=+25$, but the imaginary period would be $\approx 28.158i$.

[image: g(z)-0.1 at real(z)=-25]

Comment: Its not completely clear to me yet.

Comment: Here are things I might add to the answer: 1) The formal schroeder equations; the formal inverse Schroeder equations.  2) a graph of $g(z)\approx h(z)$ at the real axis.  3) a graph of $\theta(z)$ at the real axis.  4) a graph of g(z) at imag(period_g/2).   5) a graph of h(z) at imag(period_h/2).  Do any of those things interest you?

Comment: Turns out this example, iterating $z \mapsto z+z^2-0.01$, has a very small $\theta(z)$ sinusoidal amplitude, on the order of $5\cdot 10^{-40}$.  In fact, $g(z) \approx h(z)$.  By definition, $\theta(z)=h^{-1}(g(z))-z$.

Comment: In this solution, $\theta(z)$ is analytic, with singularities at $|\Im(z)|\approx 14.0788i$, $g(z)$ is entire, and $h(z)$ is analytic over the right half of the complex plane, and near the real axis, except where noted.  The Op's question seems to suggest that all three functions, $\theta(z),\;g(z),\;h(z)$ be entire.  I'm pretty sure that's impossible since the amplitude of an entire $\theta(z)$ grows arbitrarily large as $|\Im(z)|$ increases.

Comment: Thank you Sheldon for your answer.
Although I did not completely digest it yet , it seems correct.
Its intresting you noted that the case where all 3 functions are entire probably has no solution. I agree but love to see a proof of that.
Your complex dynamics skills are (getting ?) impressive !
I do not know who are considered the best in complex dynamics today but you together with the top posters of the tetration forum certainly seem like the future for dynamics as far as I know ... ( big words I know :p )

Comment: Thanks Mick.  Even though it does seem obviously true, I'm not sure how to prove there is no solution where all three functions are entire.  Though I've been thinking about related problems for awhile.  The thought process is that periodic functions must go to a constant in some direction in the complex plane, and yet $\theta(z)$ is taking on all values in every 1-cyclic strip... perhaps one can show that $g(z+\theta(z))$ must also take on all values in every strip?

Comment: You may want to add the complex-dynamics tag, since the known solution involves complex dynamics.

Comment: Its not because an answer involves complex dynamics that the OP needs that tag.
Im also curious about non-analytic solutions for instance.

Comment: Btw in reply to your 2nd last comment :
exp(z) does not take on every value in the strip 0 < Re < 1.
Also taking on every value in a strip (or not) does not imply periodicity per se.

Comment: The Op's question involves $g(z+\theta(z))$ where $\theta(z)$ is real periodic.  So the real strip would naturally be the real period of $\theta(z)$.  And in that strip, if $\theta(z)$ is entire, then $\theta(z)$ would take on all values.  btw, just as there are formal equations for the Schroeder functions, that lead to periodic $f^z$ functions, so one can also do the reverse!  From the $g(z)$ complex periodic function, I can generate an $f(z)$ with any real iteration. I like ... I choose the period of $\theta(z)$.  btw. (not sure how to prove it, but I've done the Taylor series calculations).